# How to open account manager window without status bar in android

Tags: android, accountmanager

I can hide status bar in my app but when account manager window is opened with an intent, status bar is shown suddenly.

This is my AccountManagerFuture:

```
AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> futBundle = acctMgr.addAccount("com.google", null, null, options, null, null, null);

new SignInTask().execute(futBundle);
```

and this is my AsyncTask:

```
 private class SignInTask extends AsyncTask<AccountManagerFuture<Bundle>, Void, Intent> {

    @Override
    protected Intent doInBackground(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle>... params) {

        try {
            googleSignInWorkFlow = (Intent) (params[0].getResult()).get(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return googleSignInWorkFlow;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Intent intent) {
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1407);
    }
}
```